# Interaction between Javascript and Python

Tags: javascript, python, server

Let's say I have set up a local server by typing `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` into the command line. In my directory, I have this `index.html` file which is an html form that receives a name from the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Enter names in the fields, then click "Submit" to submit the form:</p>
<form id="frm1">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the same directory, I have a Python file that needs to receive the input name from JavaScript. It is supposed to do some sort of analysis on it and maybe returns the new values back later.

I'd like to know how it is possible to pass the textual input over to the Python script.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use SimpleHTTPServer for that. Use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) in the simple case and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) in the larger one. I'm assuming you're rather new to this sort of thing though, so maybe stick with flask for a few weeks, Django can be a bit overwhelming when you start out.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Do stuff
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic framework is, HTML and javascript runs in the client, and python (SimpleHTTPServer) runs the in server.

So I think you need a **form** in your HTML, which will **POST** the user name to python server program.

Here is an example of python server: http://www.acmesystems.it/python_httpserver
And here is example of **form** : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp . The *action* attribute must be set correctly for python program to be invoked.